# Подключение разных включаемых областей при переходе на разные страницы

Tags: php, битрикс

Ребят подскажите решение данной задачи. В хедере шаблона есть включаемая  область

```
 <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
        "bitrix:main.include",
        "",
        Array(
            "AREA_FILE_SHOW" => "page",
            "AREA_FILE_SUFFIX" => "inc_main_picture",
            "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
            "EDIT_TEMPLATE" => ""
        )
    );?>
```

Вопрос в следующем, как сделать чтобы при переходе, допустим на страницу каталог ,вместо описанной выше включаемой области подключалась другая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое -- `if`, в котором вы проверяете соответствие страницы шаблону.

```
<?php if (strpos($APPLICATION->GetCurPage(false), 'catalog') !== false) { $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
        "bitrix:main.include",
        "",
        Array(
            "AREA_FILE_SHOW" => "page",
            "AREA_FILE_SUFFIX" => "inc_main_picture",
            "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
            "EDIT_TEMPLATE" => ""
        )
    ); } ?>
```

Comment: Всем большое спасибо, а как сделать если  на одной странице у нас есть инфоблок с товарами и для каждого раздела товаров нужна своя включаемая область?

Comment: Делаете if-else и какое-нибудь другое условие, ничего сложного

Answer (score 1):

Вариант описанный битриксом не подойдет?
http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=5409&LESSON_PATH=3913.4564.4881.5409

### Пример использования Включаемых областей

**Задача:** Сайт разделен на несколько разделов. По замыслу у каждого раздела должна быть своя «шапка» в дизайне. Более в дизайне ничего не меняется. Как лучше реализовать смену «шапок» разделов?

**Решение:** В шаблон подключается компонент "Включаемая область (для раздела)":

```php
<div id="header">
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:main.include", ".default", array(
   "AREA_FILE_SHOW" => "sect",
   "AREA_FILE_SUFFIX" => "headerinc",
   "AREA_FILE_RECURSIVE" => "Y",
   "EDIT_TEMPLATE" => "sect_headerinc.php"
   ),
   false
);?>
</div>
```

Код шапки каждого из разделов будет храниться в файле **sect_headerinc.php**. Параметр "AREA_FILE_RECURSIVE" => "Y" означает, что такая же "шапка" появится у всех подразделов данного раздела, если родительский **sect_headerinc.php** не будет специально перекрыт у кого-то из нижележащих разделов.

Comment: желательно не давать ссылки на сторонние ресурсы, т.к. их контент может стать недоступен.

Answer (score 1):

```
//для вложеных подразделов
$url=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
if(substr_count($url, "/catalog/")){ 
   $inc="inc_musical_instruments";//шаблон включаемой области
}else{
 //....
}
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:main.include",
    "",
    Array(
        "AREA_FILE_SHOW" => "page",
        "AREA_FILE_SUFFIX" => $inc,
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => ".default", 
        "EDIT_TEMPLATE" => ""
    )
);
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?